# Reaching a limit when executing python scripts from node.js

Tags: python, node.js, docker, spawn, alpine-linux

I am executing python scripts through node.js using express and spawn (I am executing them within an Alpine Container).

Python scripts write json data within the stdout using:

```
print(json_data, file=sys.stdout)
```

Whereas the node.js script read the input with:

```
var child = spawn(...);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      res.json(JSON.parse(data.toString()).data);
});
```

Unfortunately, I reach a limit at `2^16` bytes with an *Unexpected end of JSON* input error message.

When redirecting the output fto a file from Python script, the file is complete.

I haven't seen any limit neither from `spawn` nor from `write` within both documention.

Moreover, `sys.maxsize`returns `2^32`. Any explanation?

Comment: Check that question. pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr have limits, in linux is 65536 bytes.

Comment: Great, you have saved my day.